# Can I read public variables of a smart contract on Hedera Hashgraph using the mirror node API?

Tags: hedera-hashgraph

Is it feasible to retrieve the value of a public variable in my smart contract directly from a mirror node, or do I have to create a particular event that can be read by the mirror node ?
I am aware that I can query the smart contract, but I am curious about this alternative approach.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

No, the mirror nodes does not support querying smart contract variables at the moment. The engineering team is working on it to make it possible.